# Program to change vowel to its index number in string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

This is a program to change a vowel into its index:

```
 def vowel_2_index(string)  
   return '' if string.nil?  
   arr = string.enum_for(:scan,/[aeiou]/i).map {Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }  
   s_arr = arr.map{|x| x+1 }  
   arr.each_with_index{|x,y| string[x] = s_arr[y].to_s}   
   string  
 end
```

Can anyone tell me why it's failing to pass  'Codewars is the best site in the world'?

When I try to pass a testcase like:

```
Test.assert_equals(vowel_2_index('Codewars is the best site in the world'),'C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld')
```

it outputs something like:

```
"C2d4w6rs 10s t15e18bes232527ite32i35 the world"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, when you start replacing vowels with their positions it works while the position is a single digit (i.e. `1` or `5`), but when position becomes 2-digit (`10` and bigger) all found indexes start to shift and `arr` information is not correct anymore.

I'd propose to use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), since you want to do a global search and replace, you almost did it right:

```
str = 'Codewars is the best site in the world'    
str.gsub(/[aeiou]/) { |item| Regexp.last_match.begin(0) + 1 }
# => "C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld"
```

Comment: Thanks man i did not know about this behaviour of index in ruby ..solved my problem with your help......Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm not a native English speaker, so I ask to forgive me if my comment seem rude or unbecoming to you. Do you propose not to promote my own answer but generally educate about accepting answers and ask OP to select an answer? If so, I agree, that would be fair.

Comment: Sorry not getting you exactly by what you commented...can you tell me what's the exact point? have i made mistake?

Comment: Jay, Alexey's comment is a reply to a comment I left and subsequently deleted.

Answer (score 3):

All of the following refers to:

```
str = 'Codewars is the best site in the world'
```

As to the problem you are having, let's break it down:

```
enum = str.enum_for(:scan,/[aeiou]/i)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "Codewars is the best site in the world":scan(/[aeiou]/i)>
```

To see the elements of this enumerator that are passed by `map` to its block, we can convert it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> ["o", "e", "a", "i", "e", "e", "i", "e", "i", "e", "o"]
```

Continuing:

```
arr = enum.map {Regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
  #=> [1, 3, 5, 9, 14, 17, 22, 24, 26, 31, 34] 
s_arr = arr.map{|x| x+1 }  
  #=> [2, 4, 6, 10, 15, 18, 23, 25, 27, 32, 35] 
arr.each_with_index{|x,y| string[x] = s_arr[y].to_s}   
  #=> [1, 3, 5, 9, 14, 17, 22, 24, 26, 31, 34] 
str
  #=> "C2d4w6rs 10s t15e18bes232527ite32i35 the world"
```

The method should return:

```
  #=> "C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld"
```

So you see the divergence begins with `'h'` in `'the'`, which is at index `13`. The problem occurs when element `10` of `arr` is passed to the block. At this point,

```
str
  #=>  "C2d4w6rs is the best site in the world"
```

The block variables are set to:

```
x,y = [10, 3]
x #=> 10
y #=> 3
```

so the block calculation is:

```
str[10] = s_arr[3].to_s
  #=>      = "10"
```

and now:

```
str
  #=> "C2d4w6rs 10s the best site in the world"
```

As you see, the indices of all the letters following `10` have increased by one. This wasn't a problem earlier because the first three characters were each replaced with a single-digit number. The remaining elements of `arr` and `s_arr` are now off by one, and after the next replacement the indices of those that remain will be off by two, and so on.

```
                           *********
```

I would use one of the following approaches.

```
VOWELS = 'aeiouAEIOU'
```

**#1**

```
pos = '0'
str.gsub(/./) { |c| pos.next!; VOWELS.include?(c) ? pos : c }
  #=> "C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld"
```

**#2**

```
str.each_char.with_index(1).map { |c,i| VOWELS.include?(c) ? i.to_s : c }.join
  #=> "C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld"
```

**#3**

```
str.size.times.map { |i| VOWELS.include?(str[i]) ? (i+1).to_s : str[i] }.join
  #=> "C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld"
```

I have a slight preference for #1 because it operates on the string directly, as opposed to creating an array and then joining its elements back into a string. Moreover, I think it reads best.

Comment: Thanks......and yeah i got the alternative solution for my problem like 
`string.chars.each_with_index.map { |c, i| [aeiou]/i.match(c) ? (i + 1).to_s : c }.join`....just want to know why above solution is not working.....what's the behaviour of indexing....

Comment: Did I not adequately explain the problem with the code in your question?

Comment: Your explanation is very lucid for me .......
i appreciate your help for this and approach #1 is very intelligent and unique for me. Thanks for your concern ....

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'Codewars is the best site in the world'
```

You can split string to array of chars and compare each value with the regex.Am using with_index(1) because array is zero based.

```
str.split(//).map.with_index(1){|k,v| /[aeiou]/=~k ? v : k}.join
```

Which results to:

```
#=> 'C2d4w6rs 10s th15 b18st s23t25 27n th32 w35rld'
```